# If status equals true then change to "uitgeleend"

Tags: sql

I am trying to query items from a table where a status can be either true or false.

If the status is true I want the value to be changed to "Uitgeleend" (loaned, in Dutch). Also, if the status is false I want the value returned to be "Binnen" (In Stock, Dutch).

Not sure how to query such. I have no clue.

Something like

```
Select convert(Item.Status, true, 'Uitgeleend') AS Status
```

or am I doing something very stupid now?

Edit: This is my original query, the Status has to be ADDED:

```
SELECT Item.Titel, Item.Uitgever, Game.PEGI, Game.EAN, convert(varchar, Item.DvU, 101) AS DatumVUitgave, Platform.Soort as Platform, Media.soort as Media, GameGenre.Genre AS Genre FROM Game LEFT JOIN ITEM ON Item.ID = Game.itemID LEFT JOIN Media ON Game.MediaID = Media.Id LEFT JOIN Platform ON Game.PlatformID = Platform.Id LEFT JOIN GameGenre ON Game.GameGenreID = GameGenre.Id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case` for this.

Assuming you're talking about a `bit` column, do this:

```
SELECT 
    Item.Titel, Item.Uitgever, Game.PEGI, Game.EAN, 
    convert(varchar, Item.DvU, 101) AS DatumVUitgave, 
    Platform.Soort as Platform, Media.soort as Media, 
    GameGenre.Genre AS Genre,
    -- here's your new column:
    case when Item.Status=1 then 'Uitgeleend' else 'Binnen' end as Status
FROM Game 
LEFT JOIN ITEM ON Item.ID = Game.itemID 
LEFT JOIN Media ON Game.MediaID = Media.Id 
LEFT JOIN Platform ON Game.PlatformID = Platform.Id 
LEFT JOIN GameGenre ON Game.GameGenreID = GameGenre.Id
```

If it's an actual string "true", then just change `1` to `'true'`.

`convert` is for changing the type of a column - for example converting a number to text, or text to a datetime.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am also adding other stuff in the query. Where would I place the part you just wrote?

Comment: It worked! I forgot the comma when adding your line. Thanks a bunch!